# jQuery load function and tables

Tags: javascript, html

On my site, it displays a table of data.

I've got a link that will load another table of data from a URL.

```
$("#another").click(function() {
    var newGeneration = $('<p />').load('another.php?cycle=' + i);
    $('tbody').append(newGeneration);
    i++;
});
```

Is there a way to get it so that it doesn't add a p tag and just directly load the file into the tbody? I tried changing it to tr, but that just made trs inside of trs.

The code that displays another result

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $keys[$k] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $jobs[$k] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

What I don't want to happen (like it is now)

[image: don't want the p tag here]

Comment: It better to send get request, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its better to send a get request instead of complicating the use of load.

```
$("#another").click(function() {
    $.get('another.php', { 'cycle' : i }, function(data) {
         $('tbody').append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This code works perfectly. I'm very new to jQuery and did not know there was a function for sending GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the html() from the element :

```
$("#another").click(function() {
    var newGeneration = $('<p />').load('another.php?cycle=' + i);
    $('tbody').append(newGeneration.html());
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Now nothing happens when I click it :/

Comment: what if you make that a jQuery element? like $('tbody').append($(newGeneration.html()));

Comment: you are right, there must be a callback function for complete.